# Is it possible to separate last digits in Php?

Tags: php

I have a string value which size 11(2): `00000700000`

I want to convert this string to decimal. I clean leading zeros with `ltrim` function and then put comma at the end of the value with the function `substr_replace`:

```
ltrim(substr_replace( '00000700000', '.', -2, 0), '0')
```

The expected result is:

`7000.00`

Are there any cleaner way to separate last two digits with dot and convert this string to decimal?

Comment: Define “cleaner”? What do you feel is unclean about your current approach? Also your expected result doesn’t seem to match the description

Comment: Why should 00000700000 be 7000 and not 700000?

Comment: It’s common to store currency without decimals @maio290, I’m sure there are other possible explanations too

Comment: @Clive Because when the value is like `00000000000` the result will be `.00` etc. There are few more scenarios like that and I just wonder whether I can solve this without some if - else blocks in php.

Comment: @Clive I am just confused because ltrim returns a string a not even a number. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @maio290 The value should be decimal and I need to emphasise it.

Comment: Hi, the question title is a boolean question: "Is it possible to separate the last digits in Php?" to which the answer is yes. I believe this is what confuses people, you ask one question but seemingly expect another. You should clarify: Do you obtain the "expected result" but desire a simple, more elegant way to do it? Or do you not obtain the desired result? Format your question accordingly. have a good day! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply cast that string to int and divide by 100:

```php
intval('00000700000') / 100; // 7000
```

If you want that same number formatted, use `format_number()`:

```php
number_format(num: $result, decimals: 2, thousands_separator: '') // 7000.00
```

---

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=PYzNCsIwEITvhb7DHoQkUDB6EaLio4TVRFrIH7ubPr-tiHMYGL6ZuT3a3MZhHA4UuSeBOyxFVkxa2V2XrysDRzhZe92bK5IPPTf9m0xQen5G8u9KGUVvycGfhfhaMiZ2cJ5A5toZS2DPsSGhVHKglDHb8Qc%2C&v=8.2.1)